# Using Visual Studio publish with GitHub

Tags: c#, github, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am trying to use the "publish" feature of Visual Studio (2015) to publish my application, but I would like this folder to be published to my main GitHub repository. The link would be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steam-Chat-Bot/SteamChatBot/master/SteamChatBot/publish/`. I have tried many times and failed, and I would just like to know if there is an easy way to do this that works. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? What happened? If you cloned your local repository from the "main" repository, everything should work as expected.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan when I say failed I mean that it fails to install from setup.exe because something about the manifest, but I figure its because i'm publishing to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steam-Chat-Bot/SteamChatBot/master/SteamChatBot/publish/` and when I go to that page in the browser I get a 400 error.